# Contract details in JAXRS/Spring/CXF Endpoint Configuration -- Namespace, PublishedUrl, etc

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, cxf

How do I flesh out my context configuration with Endpoint details in JAXRS?

Here is what I have for JAXWS:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="s-myService" implementor="#myService" 
    serviceName="s2:MyService" 
    endpointName="e2:MyServiceEndpoint"
    address="/my-service/soap/base" 
    publishedEndpointUrl="http://localhost:8080/my-service/soap/base" 
    xmlns:s2="http://localhost:8080/example-service/ns" 
    xmlns:e2="http://localhost:8080/example-service/ns"
/>
```

How do I make the following JAXRS Endpoint implement the same details?

```
<jaxrs:server id="r-myService" 
    address="/my-service/rest/base"> 
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans> 
        <ref bean="myRestService" /> 
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans> 
    <jaxrs:providers> 
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" /> 
        <ref bean="SomethingGives"/> 
    </jaxrs:providers> 
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings> 
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" /> 
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" /> 
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings> 
</jaxrs:server>
```

I'd really like to see publishedEndpointUrl fleshed out in the REST service. The API for [JAXRSServerFactoryBean](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/JAXRSServerFactoryBean.html) implies it can be done through an inherited field. How should the context configuration be implemented?

Comment: I'm trying to test whether something Spring-wise can be adapted from the jaxws configuration in item (5) here: http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Usage-of-JaxWsServerFactoryBean-td571428.html .

Comment: did you got something on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the publishedEndpointUrl as part of your jaxrs attribute.

```
<jaxrs:server id="r-myService" 
address="/my-service/rest/base" publishedEndpointUrl="http://localhost"> 
<jaxrs:serviceBeans> 
    <ref bean="myRestService" /> 
</jaxrs:serviceBeans> 
<jaxrs:providers> 
    <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" /> 
    <ref bean="SomethingGives"/> 
</jaxrs:providers> 
<jaxrs:extensionMappings> 
    <entry key="json" value="application/json" /> 
    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" /> 
</jaxrs:extensionMappings>
```